# Looper, worker thread and other concurrency issues

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

Can someone please explain to me in short the following terms, and how they relate to each other?

1. `handler` - each thread has a handler? each view has a handler?
   perform the `post()`.
   there is a default handler for the OS main thread?
2. `looper` -
3. `looper thread` -
4. `post` - adding a runnable to the end of the thread's tasks queue
5. `task` - a runnable or a message
6. `executor` - manages a threads' pool to execute some tasks. useful if preforming the same task few times.
7. `timer` -
8. `runnable vs message` - when to use each of them?
9. `thread's queue` - each thread has a tasks queue.

Any other terms I should be familiar with
regarding concurrency issues in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain shortly but to fully understand those terms I'll have to practice developing android applications.

**handler**: an object attached to a thread (any thread) that both processes messages and executes runnables in its thread. That is important sometimes because i.e. only the UI thread can do operations on views, and sometimes a background thread must use an UI thread handler to do action in the views

**looper** is an object that iterates through a thread message queue, popping runnables and messages and giving them to the thread handlers. The UI thread comes already with a Looper running

**looper thread** is the thread of a given looper, nothing special here

**post**, **task** and **executor** ou answered yourself already

**timer** and class to manage small amounts of time. Like measuring some seconds or milliseconds, wainting some amount of time and so on.

**runnable vs message** the main difference is: when you use runnables, the poster thread mus specify the implementation of something, ehile when you use messages, the handlers specifies the implementation of some action. When your working with only one poster and one handles you can use both almost interchangeably. When you have many different threads posting the same thing to a same handler, I would use messages and vice-versa.

Comment: so how come any view has a `post()` method?

Comment: handler and looper are active objects (meaning threads) or just static mechanism? which threads run into them?

Comment: The View.post() method is just an utility Android provides you to make something run in the UI Thread. I actually don't know if Android actually delivers this code to a handler or simply let to execute the next time it is traversing the view hierarchy, but this actually doesn't matter since it as an implementation detail

Comment: Handler **is not** a thread. It is attached to a thread. Same with Looper, but it is more important that you understand Handlers first..

Comment: can you please explain how task is related to runnable and to message? implementation wise?

Comment: if things weren't confusing enough: what's the difference between `RunnableExecutor` and `Executor` ?

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to what `@hsgubert` said, there's some other concepts that's worth mentioning. Once you enter the "multithread world" you should know there are many synchronization and concurrency handling methods. As you're running things in paralell, you'll be running your app and once in a time, at different points, you'll probably get some beautiful `ConcurrentModificacionException`.

In my own experience, this is one of the biggest pains (memory leaks permitting) I've ever experienced, probably because there's not a pattern how to solve them. So I think you should also know these concepts:

- Use `synchronized` methods/variables whenever needed. In methods, it will prevent another `Thread` enter before the current `Thread` has ended its execution. It will **not** prevent other `Thread`s modify insider data structures in another methods, though, so be clear about it. Used as a `synchronized(variable_name) { ... }` block, it will prevent `variable_name` being modified **app-wide** by any other `Thread` until you exit that block.
- There are many inter-`Thread` synchronization methods. The two I use most are `Semaphore` and `CountDownLatch` (probably I use most the latter). Sometimes it might happen that you don't want to execute some code portion until some other portion (or `Thread`) has finished its execution. This methods safe lifes.
- There are several already-concurrency-prepared data structures. These datastructures basically already implement the above mentioned, so if you use `.add()` on multiple places concurrently, Java itself handles that event and manages to not show any exception. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Comment: what do you mean "add" in `so if you use .add() on multiple places concurrently`

Comment: If you access the same data structure from two different places at once, you'll get this `ConcurrentModificationException`. So it's up to you to determine some blocking mechanism to avoid this to happen, that's why you have to use `synchronized` when you know you're handling the same object from many places, in order to prevent its concurrent modification. These data structures from `java.concurrent` already have built-in mechanisms that do this without the need of setting `synchronized` by yourself, so you rely that task to the data structure management.